# Does Powerdot on MacTeX 2015 work?

Tags: mactex, powerdot

On MacTeX 2015 I'm unable to compile the following code requiring the Powerdot package. Can anyone confirm this is a bug?

```
\documentclass{powerdot}

\title{powerdot example 1}
\author{Hendri Adriaens \and Christopher Ellison}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{slide}{Slide 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is the first slide\pause
    \item There is nothing special about it.
  \end{itemize}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no error. Remember that you have to compile it with `latex` and not `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks egreg, I'm using the OS X El Capitan Beta, it must be an OS X issue then.

Comment: What are you using for typesetting? Is it TeXShop, TeXStudio or what else?

Comment: It's not an issue of the editor, here's what I get when compiling with latex:! Package xkeyval Error: `cfpos' undefined in families `template'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 
    
?

Comment: Sorry, but I get no such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Power Dot to view the output in pdf form the following steps are used:

1. Compile the code with latex. This makes a dvi file.
2. Convert the dvi file to pdf file. Most editors have a button "DVItoPDF".
3. Use the "view pdf" button to obtain said pdf.